# Error when deleting pointer in c++ dll

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, labview

I have written a dll in visual c++ that contains functions I call from labview.  I create a pointer on initialization, pass that pointer out, then use it when calling other functions.  All works fine until I try to delete that pointer, then I get an "Unhandled exception at 0x56DC514A (intelcamera.dll) in LabVIEW.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction."  Here are my exported functions:

```
extern "C"  int colorstream_init(uintptr_t *ptrOut, int *data)
{
    *ptrOut = (uintptr_t)new CDevice();
    ((CDevice*)*ptrOut)->init_camera();
    *data = ((CDevice*)*ptrOut)->get_data();
    return ((CDevice*)*ptrOut)->get_sts();
}

extern "C"  int get_image(uintptr_t ptr, uint32_t image[], int size, int *data)
{
    int rtn_val = ((CDevice*)ptr)->get_image(image, size);
    *data = ((CDevice*)ptr)->get_data();
    return rtn_val;
}

extern "C"  int close(uintptr_t ptr, uint32_t last_image[], int size)
{
//  ((CDevice*)ptr)->get_image(last_image, size);
    int r = ((CDevice*)ptr)->close();
    delete (CDevice*)ptr;
    return r;
}
```

I have tried moving the "delete (CDevice*)ptr;" line up into the get_image function and get the same exception.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: What does `CDevice` do in its destructor?

Comment: Are you certain that `ptr` is indeed the same one you provided in colorstream_init and not something that has been`memcpy`ed or otherwise replaced with a dupe that was not `new`ed?

Comment: Which camera SDK are you using? If you eliminate LabVIEW and just call those functions in a C++ application, does the crash still happen? If you eliminate the camera SDK calls and just allocate/delete a simple data structure, does the crash still occur in LabVIEW?

Comment: @AlanStokes - The only thing in the destructor is DeleteCriticalSection(&rBufferSafe);  I took the outline for my code from <http://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-VC/Create-a-continuous-data-stream-from-C-and-read-it-in-LabView/td-p/1762854>

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen - The SDK is for the Intel R200 camera.  Thanks, those are good suggestions.  I will see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem; thanks to everyone who helped.  I turns out that in the labview library call, I had the ptr input parameter passed as a "Pointer to Value", not as a "Value".  I pass it out of the init function as a "Pointer to Value," but it needs to be passed back in as a "Value" (obviously...).

This is my first time writing functions in a .dll and I apologize for taking up peoples time with a dumb mistake.